# lableStyle attribute <Toggle> doesn't change on onToggle() material-ui

Tags: reactjs

lableStyle attribute   doesn't change on onToggle()  material-ui, here is the code. I am declared 'labelstyle' property in state, but it doesn't rendered when the onToggle() invoked.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toggled:false,
      labelstyle:'red'
    };

<Toggle
 label="Remind Me"
 elementStyle={{color:'purple', backgroundColor:'cyan'}}
 defaultToggled={this.state.toggled}
 thumbStyle={styles.thumbOff}
 trackStyle={styles.trackOff}
 thumbSwitchedStyle={styles.thumbSwitched}
 trackSwitchedStyle={styles.trackSwitched}
labelStyle={this.state.labelstyle}
onToggle={()=>{this.state.toggled = !this.state.toggled;
             {console.debug('toggled ------'+this.state.toggled)}
       this.state.toggled ? this.state.labelstyle= 'green' :
                       this.state.labelstyle='red';
            {console.debug('labelstyle ------'+this.state.labelstyle)}
       }
    }
```

/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line will not work. you are not suppose to update the state like this.

```
onToggle={ () => {this.state.toggled = !this.state.toggled} };
```

This is the proper way.

```
onToggle={ () => {this.setState({toggled: !this.state.toggled}) };
```

Please read more about setting the state in the React official docs.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the basic.